# does not work module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

file ConnectToDB

```
var pg = require("pg");
var dataWithDB = require('./DataBase/ConnectToDb');
var pool = new pg.Pool({
host: "localhost",
port: "5432",
user: "postgres",
password: "111111",
database: "hrs"
});

pool.connect(function (err,client,done) {
if(err)console.log("connect "  + err.toString());

else
    client.query('SELECT id, "idName", "idContact", "idExperience", 
"idSkill", "dateAdded", "dateColloquy"' +
'FROM public."applicant ";',function (err,result) {

        if(err) {
            //console.log("query " + err.toString());
            exports.res = "Data NOT";
        }
        else {
            console.log(result.rows);
            module.exports.resul = result.rows;
        }
        done();
    });

});
pool.end()
```

file app.js

```
var dataWithDB = require('./DataBase/ConnectToDb');

console.log(dataWithDB + "  wit DB");
```

as a result deduces to me undefined wit DB
but should data from db

Can an error in the scope?
Data is sent if you specify at the end of the file module.exporst.result = "Example".

Comment: It makes no sense to have a module.exports inside a callback.

Comment: how to be then, how right?

Comment: You need to learn how `async` code works in Javascript.  In your above code you could maybe export a function that has a callback that does the DB stuff, but what I would suggest is you look into learning promises, callback's can get really messy fast.  And then following on from Promises, you could use `async / await` to make the code even easier to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should encapsulate your connect to db code in a function which takes a callback.

Here is an example, hopefully you get the idea. :)

## ./DataBase/ConnectToDb

```
var pg = require("pg");
module.exports = (callback) => {
    var pool = new pg.Pool({
        host: "localhost",
        port: "5432",
        user: "postgres",
        password: "111111",
        database: "hrs"
    });

    pool.connect(function (err, client, done) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("connect " + err.toString());
        } else {
            let query = 'SELECT id, "idName", "idContact",' +
                ' "idExperience","idSkill", "dateAdded", "dateColloquy"' +
                'FROM public."applicant ";'
            client.query(query, function (err, result) {
                if (err) {
                    //console.log("query " + err.toString());
                    exports.res = "Data NOT";
                    callback(err);
                }
                else {
                    console.log(result.rows);
                    callback(null, result);
                }
                done(); // Not sure what this does! :-o
            });
        }
    });
    // Is this trying to close it before we've connected? 
    // It should probably be up above...
    pool.end() 

}
```

## app

```
var connectToDb = require('./DataBase/ConnectToDb');
connectToDb((err, result) => {
    // This is a callback!
    if(err) console.log(err)
    else console.log(result)
})
```

Do a google search for: **node.js callback pattern**

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do: import a different callback function that you pass into your query. This callback will do whatever you want with result. As written, your method will not work and does not make sense.